# Making 256-color AND Line drawing characters both work in PuTTY

Tags: linux, terminal, putty, ncurses

I'm having trouble setting up PuTTY with Ubuntu.

I'm trying to get line characters to work in aptitude as well as 256-color support, but can only get one or the other.

- Ubuntu Config

  - Using 64-bit Ubuntu
  - Terminal type xterm-256color or putty-256color gives 256-color, but incorrect line characters.
  - Terminal type linux gives proper lines in aptitude, but only 16 colors.
- PuTTY Config

  - Using font with Unicode characters. (DejaVu Sans Mono)
  - Received Data is assumed to be in UTF-8.
  - Set to use Unicode line drawing code points.

Output from `locale`:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The problem is that PuTTY in UTF-8 mode ignores<sup>1</sup> VT100 "Alternate character set" commands, and ncurses attempts to use the "graphical" character set for drawing the GUI. (The box drawing characters are in the same positions as `klmqx` would normally be.)

`export NCURSES_NO_UTF8_ACS=1` to your environment, it should fix the problem by telling ncurses to always use Unicode box drawing characters when a UTF-8 locale is selected.

<sup>1</sup> There is a PuTTY [wishlist entry](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/putty/wishlist/utf8-plus-vt100.html) for this, along with explanation [why the current behavior is better](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/%7Emgk25/unicode.html#term).

Update (2018-05-12): It seems that this combination *will* be supported in PuTTY 0.71.

Update: PuTTY now has the option "Enable VT100 line drawing even in UTF-8 mode" in the settings Window -> Translation.

Comment: That's interesting. I just always used Lucida Console because the line drawing always just worked in UTF-8 mode. Now I can use much better fonts. Thanks. :)

Comment: I just want to point out that running through a program that converts the alternate character set to UTF-8 also fixes the problem. I found this from the link you provided. The best example program is screen.

Comment: not to dig up old posts, but [KiTTY](http://kitty.9bis.net/) - a PuTTY fork - provides a checkbox to "Allow ACS line drawing in UTF" (new/current session settings->Window->Translation) which seems to work well with apps like aptitude.

Comment: @swiss: it is not **`screen`** which does the conversion, but **`ncurses`**.

Comment: I am working in Putty and using zsh. I am having a similar problem as OP, in that in VIM, certain characters such as arrow in NERDtree are not being display. When I do "export NCURSES_NO_UTF8_ACS=1", and open VIM again, it doesnt do anything different. The arrows are still not displayed. Any idea whats going on?

Comment: @alpha_989: That's not the same problem at all, as arrows weren't part of the ACS in the first place. They're already purely UTF-8. What do you see in their place?

Comment: @grawity, if I am on the remote server, I see this: https://imgur.com/R0T4hO5

Comment: I see the arrows as expected in NERDtree. However, if I am loggin in through ssh, I see the arrows become replaced by boxes. https://imgur.com/cfejBDi

Comment: I have tried all the solutions posted on this thread here, but it didnt solve it: https://serverfault.com/questions/475925/how-to-fix-putty-showing-garbled-characters. But as you pointed out maybe the problem is not the same. Any idea how to debug this, or the root cause of this issue?

Comment: Ok.. I solved it myself. Just in case somebody else has the same problem heres the solution: https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree/issues/522#issuecomment-163673920

You can use the default Consolas font as well

Answer (score 12):

This is now implemented as an option in PuTTY [git master](https://git.tartarus.org/?p=simon/putty.git;a=commitdiff;h=6afa955a2ebf017755af134264a9423f54b9351c).

Putty 0.71 ->

Category -> Window -> Translation -> tick "Enable VT100 line drawing even in UTF-8 mode"

[image: screenshot]

Comment: This solved a similar problem I was having (I'm using PuTTY Release 0.73). Thanks!