# Why does YaST now show lines as lqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq?

Tags: linux, opensuse, ncurses, yast

Today my YaST started rendering lines like this:

[image: l and q instead of lines]

It makes it difficult to read.. Any idea what this is about and how I can fix it? I tried rebooting, no dice.

Edit -- here's my PuTTY config:

[image: PuTTY config page showing translation window]

Character set is UTF-8

Comment: [grawity](http://superuser.com/questions/278286/) will tell you exactly what the problem is when you [edit] your question to tell the world what character encoding you've configured PuTTY to use.  (-:

Comment: i've edited the post to show my putty character encoding.. does that explain anything?

Comment: so anyone has a solution?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

in bash, type: `export NCURSES_NO_UTF8_ACS=1`

Comment: Or, more likely, you want to add this to your `~/.bashrc` file so it happens automatically when you log in.

Answer (score 27):

Change "Terminal-type string" from "xterm" to "linux" in Connection>Data.

Comment: This answer needs more love!

Comment: I too prefer the putty answer - this terminal-type should be the default for every putty session

Comment: **This** should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 7):

Permanent solution for your problem:

For one user:

```
cd ~
echo "export NCURSES_NO_UTF8_ACS=1" >> .bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

The last line applies changes to the current terminal immediately.

For all users:

```
echo "export NCURSES_NO_UTF8_ACS=1" >> /etc/bash.bashrc.local
```