# NetTerm shows characters instead of lines

Tags: character-encoding, special-characters, ascii

My issue is almost the same as [Why does YaST now show lines as lqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq?](https://superuser.com/questions/735269/why-does-yast-now-show-lines-as-lqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq) , but instead of PuTTY and YaST, I'm using NetTerm and MLS (= WMS). My lines are also shown in characters as you can see here:
[image]
I can't seem to be able to change the character set to UTF-8 so I'm afraid it is only working with ASCII. That's why I don't think the given solution in the related article works for me (see below).

```
export NCURSES_NO_UTF8_ACS=1
```

Also, this global setting doesn't really seem to work (I tried both options).
[image: this global setting]

Funny thing is, the lines actually show the first time you connect to the phone directory (after a Windows start). If you keep opening new sessions, it will keep working. Once you close NetTerm and restart it (without a reboot of your system/Windows), it won't work anymore.
Another funny thing is that all users (about 150) have the same issue, apart from the "admin" user. I checked his netterm.ini file with mine, but they both are similar (apart from color settings and such).

Anyone who can help me with the issue?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: EXTRA: I work with emulation VT220 (tried other VT-versions as well, but didn't work), nor does XTERM

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, I use vt220 emulation vt220 keys and putting the isi_vga font solved this problem in the company I work for.