# PuTTY and curses line display issue

Tags: windows-7, putty

I have a user that's utilizing a piece of software written in Perl and uses curses for it's display logic.  The software works perfectly for a lot of other people, it's this one user that has the issue.

I've ensured we're running the same version of PuTTY as him, and share the exact same config (I exported his settings and imported them onto my machine, and it worked).

But no matter what we try (we've played around with the character encoding, making sure that UNICODE line characters are interpreted right, and even the terminal type), he always gets "0's" and other characters instead of vertical and horizontal lines in the curses menu when on UTF-8 (it acts wonky on other character encodings).

We're running the same OS but probably drastically different OS configs.  My thought it to start chasing the character encoding on his machine but I'm not quite sure where to start there.

Comment: I would start by comparing the output of the (bash) command **set | egrep '^(LC|LANG)'**

Comment: Also, could you confirm that `printf '\342\224\224\342\224\200\342\224\220'` shows the line drawings correctly?

Answer (score 3):

grawity got the line issue correct with [Making 256-color AND Line drawing characters both work in PuTTY](https://superuser.com/questions/278286/making-256-color-and-line-drawing-characters-both-work-in-putty)  I did also have to change the terminal type back to xterm as well back from "putty", but this has corrected the issue.

Comment: Changing the terminal type to "linux" seems to fix the most issues.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using PuTTY, I presume you login to a remote (ssh) server and run the program there. You will probably use different login accounts with, perhaps, different locale settings. Try running **locale**, which will output **LANG**, **LANGUAGE**, and several **LC_*** variables. Check whether those are the same. Also check the **TERM** variable on the (remote?) machine. This gives a bit more info than *tlund*'s option.

You can also check which **font** you are using. It is possible that some fonts do not have the glyphs available for extended ASCII